# Display images with a loop in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, import, dynamic-import

I am using Gatbyjs, and I would like to display multiple images in a card component. It seems that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713362/how-to-render-images-with-react-js-using-map-or-loop) shoud work, but it does not. I don't get any other specific error than:

```
GEThttp://localhost:8000/[object Module]
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 13ms]
```

I tried to use an absolute path for the `src` attribute and it didn't work either. Neither did something nasty like importing every images in the file of the card component, and calling them this way:

```
<img src={`${Img}`} />.
```

Here is the component:

```
const ServiceCard = ({ title, subtitle, text, logos }) => {
    const displayLogos = logos.split(",").map((logo) => (
        <li key={logo} className="tech-logo">
            <img
                key={logo}
                src={require(`../../images/tech-logos/${logo}.png`)}
                alt={`${logo} logo`}
                height="30px"
                width="30px"
            />
        </li>
    ));

    return (
        <div className="service-card">
            <h1 className="service-card-title">{title}</h1>
            <h2 className="service-card-subtitle">{subtitle}</h2>
            <p className="service-card-text">{text}</p>
            <ul className="tech-logo-list">{displayLogos}</ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Edit:**
This is the way this component is used :

```
<ServiceCard
    title="Text string"
    subtitle="e-shop"
    text="random text"  
    logos="React,Ror,Gatsby,Wordpress,Drupal,Js,Php,Mysql,Pgsql"
/>
```

So as we can expect, `console.log("tech is " + logo);` in `displayLogos` returns a new string for every string concatenated between comma.

Comment: Question, are you at least able to import and view one of the images in your component (without the loop)?  Just to verify path and accessibility to the image.

Comment: Yes, if I do it the regular way it works : `import testimg from "../../images/tech-logos/React.png";` and `<img src={testimg} />`.

Comment: This question is focusing on the React/looping aspect, but it seems like really what you need to look for is solutions to a dynamic `require()` Could you perhaps require the entire directory of logo images at the top of the file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve this by adding `.default` at the end of the `require()`:

```
    const displayLogos = logos.map((logo) => (
        <li key={logo} className="tech-logo">
            <img
                key={logo}
                src={require(`../../images/tech-logos/${logo}.png`).default}
                alt={`${logo} logo`}
                height="30px"
                width="30px"
            />
        </li>
    ));
```

Found the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264111/in-react-how-do-i-use-require-for-an-image).